# Convert UTC date as it is to target format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have date in 2019-12-07T14:55:00.000Z which I want to convert to target format without effecting original value by browser's timezone using momentjs. I tried `moment('2019-12-07T14:55:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')`, but it is converting it to 12/07/2019 6:55 (because browser timezone is PST) whereas I expect it to be 12/07/2019 14:55

Comment: Try moment.utc(date).format

Comment: yeah..got it, thanks

Comment: While this question is about moment.js, it is still worth noting that the built-in js date formatting functions (Date or Intl) now let you specify an explicit timezone (in the options parameter) so in a case like this you could specify GMT/UTC to avoid it picking up the browser's timezone.

Answer (score -2):

we can use utc function to prevent moment to use browser's timezone , just like below

```
moment.utc('2019-12-07T14:55:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. Add some more information about how the function works and why this is the answer.